# Grouping four applications under a single app icon in android

Tags: android, grouping

In my android application I have to use a single icon for four different applications ,that means when I click the main icon then four different app icons has to be appear and when I click an app icon a different  application has to be opened for each icon.

and

when I installed the new applications the app icon has to be created under the main icon only.

Is it possible ?
If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not bundle them all into one apk, then have your first activity shown as a menu screen that has 4 icons, when you click on one it takes you to the relevant activity?

I know this is a bit of a workaround, and it wouldn't work if the apps for example have to be installed seperatley but was just a thought.

Comment: This seems the easiest approach. You could also set the theme (for example, <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"> in your manifest) of the main menu Activity to give the illusion of a folder.

Answer (score 0):

My first approach would be to do this with a widget: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

You could open a dialog with it and send an intent depending on choice that the desired application can handle.